# Bootstrap date-picker popup disappears on scrolling the window

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker, eyecon-plugin

I am currently using bootstrap date picker downloaded from [**eyecon.ro**](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

On clicking the input field the datepicker popup opens, where i am showing the date.
However, on scrolling the browser's window, the datepicker's popup disappears. I have also created an issue for this in [**github**](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/1054) but haven't got any answer yet. Can anyone help me with this, please ?

Answer (score 0):

When you click in any location on windows the event "onblur" is fired, so this is not a bug. Otherwise you can modify this coding a event for onblur to not 'hide' the datepicker window.

**Edit:**
Ok, make this modification on bootstrap-datepicker.JS, on Datepicker prototype (line 88):

```
show: function(e) {
        this.picker.show();
        this.height = this.component ? this.component.outerHeight() : this.element.outerHeight();
        this.place();
        var t = this;
        $(window).on('resize', $.proxy(this.place, this));
        $(window).on("scroll", this.place, function() {
            t.show();
        });
        if (e ) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (!this.isInput) {
        }
        var that = this;
        $(document).on('mousedown', function(ev){
            if ($(ev.target).closest('.datepicker').length == 0) {
                that.hide();
            }
        });
        this.element.trigger({
            type: 'show',
            date: this.date
        });
    },
```

I just include a trigger for 'scroll', below the trigger for 'rezise' (line 6 here).